# COUNT field incorrect or syntax error inside of PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm developing changes to the data in a table once a button is clicked on a web but the next error comes out:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 07002
            [SQLSTATE] => 07002
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error
        )

)
```

I've reviewed the code for a few hours but I haven't found the typo. This is the code:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$serverName = "serverName\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dataBase", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"pass");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn === false ) {                                  
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql1 = "DECLARE @a INT ". PHP_EOL;
$sql1 .= "SELECT @a = condLot FROM productos WHERE prodID = ? ". PHP_EOL;
$sql1 .= "IF (@a > 0) ". PHP_EOL;
$sql1 .= "UPDATE productos SET estadoAl = (estadoAl + 1), condLot = (condLot - 1) FROM productos WHERE prodID = ? ". PHP_EOL;
$sql1 .= "ELSE ". PHP_EOL;
$sql1 .= "UPDATE productos SET estadoAl = (estadoAl + 1) FROM productos WHERE prodID = ? ". PHP_EOL;
$var = array($_GET["idProd"]);


$stmt1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql1, $var);
if( $stmt1 === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, syntax of your update query is not correct

Comment: Remove `FROM productos` from update query

Comment: @Ravi in the SQL Server MS works but explain me what is wrong, please.

Comment: Thanks, @B.Desai. I don't understand why with the "FROM" worked in the SQL Server MS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update queries don't have `from` clause. Try the following code.

```
$sql1 .= "UPDATE productos SET estadoAl = (estadoAl + 1), condLot = (condLot - 1) WHERE prodID = ? ". PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thanks. Like I wrote in a comment I don't understand why with the "FROM" worked in the SQL Server MS.

Comment: As far as I know, even SQL Server should throw an error if you use `From` clause. No matter whether it works or not, technically Update queries don't have from clause.